# Where do all the doors lead to?

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual, history

You are walking in a hallway and find a door.
You decide to enter the room. The door closes behind you, the room suddenly becomes dark and starts spinning.
You fall on the floor in the middle of the room, totally disoriented. You have no idea which way you came from.
The light is back on.

There are four doors - one at each side:

[image: red]

[image: blue]

[image: yellow]

[image: orange]

**Where do all the doors lead to?** Which one would you choose and why?

Note: Excuse my poor drawing skills.

PS. Due to my poor drawing skills, I decided to change the second image. Hopefully, it is less confusing now.

Comment: +1 for the awesome drawings  Specially for the "cat". :)

Comment: @Marius - it is not a cat. :) Hahaha.

Comment: What cat o.O I see a devil 3:P

Comment: @MariaDeleva. that's why I put it in quotes. Everyone can see that it's actually a cow on 2 legs :D. Neh...just having some fun, don't take this the wrong way.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Is the exact time on pic.2 important?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov, it is but what is the exact time? ;)

Comment: @MariaDeleva is that asterisk (in 2nd image)?

Comment: @smriti, it is asterisk, I used, yes. But what does it depict?

Comment: @MariaDeleva does it depict 'snowflake'? and if so, then does the certain game comes into picture?

Comment: @smriti, it does depict snowflake, I don't know what game you are talking about.

Comment: What's that arrow in the first picture??

Comment: @Sid, the devil's tail. :) Is the drawing so bad?

Comment: @dcfyj - I have already given upvotes to everyone who attempted to answer the question. But the answer for the first door is missing. So, as soon as we have that, someone might make a community answer - not sure how to do one.

Comment: @MariaDeleva When you go to answer there's a little checkbox in the bottom right corner you can tick, that'll turn it into a community answer. Also I only see 1 clue for the first door, where's the second? The door color?

Comment: @dcfyj, let's just say that you should be able to deduce 2 different things for number 1. And they are specific enough to reach an answer.

Comment: No point going for an answer now but here are my 2 cents about the first image: it could be the Smiling Devil tattoo & piercing shop which was opened in 1999 in Hawaii. Not exactly evil but not where we want to be either (seeing as we're trying to go back the way we came).

Comment: I would take door number 1, how could you not trust that smile?

Comment: Ah. I am surprised no one has solved door number 1 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the 4 different puzzle parts were solved by 4 different people, I am adding this community wiki answer with links to their answers as they should be the ones receiving upvotes:

Door 1 was solved by [March Ho](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/7529/march-ho): https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41523/29050

> 1666 - The Great Fire of London

In March Ho's own words:

> Since Door 1 is the only unsolved door, here is my guess:
>
>  The Devil refers to the [Number of the Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast) (usually quoted as 666).
>
>   Additionally,
>   The [Great Fire of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_London) occurred in the year 1666, which is linked to the red colour due to the fire.

Additional details:

> Hell usually is associated with fire. In addition, the devil is smiling, so he probably feels at home wherever this place is. Thus, additional hints for the fire. Also, by pure coincidence, if you write 666 and fire in Google, one of the first suggestions is the Great fire in London, 1666.

Door 2 was solved by [Yandrakus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28721/yandrakus): https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41503/29050

> 1812 - Napoleon's invasion of Russia

In Yandrakis' own words:

> Could be that Door nº2 leads to...
>  
>  Napoleonic invasion to Russia
>
>  Because:
>
>  The time on the clock is set at 18:12 (I think), and the symbol (asterisk) depicted on the door is related to a snow flake. Napoleon tried to invade Russia during winter and this was one of his biggest mistakes in his military career.

Additional details:

> The light blue color of the door is intentional - to represent ice, snow, winter.

Door 3 was solved by [Radoslav Hristov](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21543/radoslav-hristov): https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41497/29050

> 2016 - the present

In Radoslav Hristov's own words:

> 3rd door:
>
>  It is a whole number 5776 and refers to "The year of Light" a.k.a. "Beginning of the End of Time". Further on the same: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Lucis the 2016 a.d. actually is anno lucis, or year of light 2016, i.e. the current year!

Additional details:

> It was only natural that there would be a door leading to back where we came from (the hallway, presumably the present). The yellow color is not intentional and does not have hidden meaning.

Door 4 was solved by [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan): https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41502/29050

> 1773 - The Boston Tea Party

In Gareth McCaughan's own words:

> I think the fourth door might possibly be
>
>   pointing to *tea*, or perhaps more specifically to the Boston Tea Party.
>
>   The quotation
>
>   is from Psalm 73 verse 17, perhaps suggesting the year 1773
>
>   and the plant on the door
>
>   seems like it might plausibly be a tea plant.

Additional notes:

> The orange color of the door and the brownish color of the text actually resemble the color of the drink itself (tea). The leaf is indeed a tea leaf.

Comment: Maria, you should checkmarkify this one too unless you feel that one of the other answers is so fantastically good that it deserves the checkmark even though this is the only one with the whole answer.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, since I posted it, even though it is community wiki, I can't tick it - it says I should wait 2 days. I wanted to mark it, so that the links to all the answers are on top and the votes go to the respective people (you are one of them), but the system would not allow me.

Comment: How annoying. Oh well, just wait the two days, I guess.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, would it be appropriate to add my own reasoning and also include the reasoning of each of you? I mean, to add minor details that could have been missed?

Comment: Yes, absolutely it would.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, I added the additional information. :) Now the answer is indeed complete.

Answer (score 19):

I think the fourth door might possibly be

> pointing to *tea*, or perhaps more specifically to the Boston Tea Party.

The quotation

> is from Psalm 73 verse 17, perhaps suggesting the year 1773

and the plant on the door

> seems like it might plausibly be a tea plant.

(This has been confirmed by the questioner in comments. Thanks, Maria!)

Now, the time on door 2 looks to me like

> it might be 18:12; I think this may well refer to Napoleon's failed invasion of Russia in that year, which failed because of the very cold winter, hence the snowflake.

(... and now I look at other answers I see that Yandrakus got there first and his answer has been confirmed correct.)

So, so far it seems that:

> *Door 1* takes us to some currently-unknown place signified by a devil and redness. Seems distinctly unpromising, but the straightforward interpretation that this leads to hell has been guessed by about 666 people and explicitly rejected by the questioner. There are any number of things known by titles resembling "Red Devil(s)" and some of them have dates (e.g., of foundation) associated with them, but it seems like we need something cleverer...
>  *Door 2* will dump us in the middle of Napoleon's army's defeat at the hands of the ferocious Russian winter. No thanks.
>  *Door 3* will dump us back in the present. Seems like a pretty good option.
>  *Door 4* will drop us in the harbour at Boston in late 1773, and there will be no tea to drink any more.

---

Some ideas that have been confirmed by the questioner to be *wrong*:

> I wondered whether there might be a general theme of drinks to go with the Boston Tea Party behind door 4. Nope.

> I thought Radoslav's suggestion of using "anno lucis" dating had been confirmed by the questioner and meant that door 3 said 1776. But apparently I misunderstood that; it's year 5776 in the Hebrew calendar, which is the year we're in right now. (Which, incidentally, probably means that that's the door we should take.)

> I wondered whether other doors might have corresponding US cities -- Hell, Michigan for door 1; Waterloo, Iowa (because of 18:12, except that of course Waterloo was actually 1815 not 1812 and I'm an idiot) for door 2; Independence, Missouri (because of 1776) for door 3. All wrong, I think.

Comment: You are correct about the 4th door. Your assumption about the rest is wrong, though.

Comment: The question is "where", but it doesn't mean it leads to a specific place as in city. I already said that RadoslavHristov was correct with his answer for the 3rd door.  You are on the right path for the second door. As you see, door 4 leads to an event.

Comment: I can't make sense of most of Radoslav's answer for the 3rd door. A.L. is just a system of dates that's offset by 4000 years relative to our usual ones. Radoslav said that A.L.2016 = 2016AD, but that's just wrong. On the other hand, year 5776 *in the Hebrew calendar* is (or more precisely overlaps) the present year. I'm not sure exactly what it is you were saying he got right :-).

Comment: Quote from his answer: " i.e. the current year!".

Comment: Ah, OK. It looks to me as if he got that right by accident, then, but maybe I misunderstood :-). Anyway, in that case I bet that's the door we should take. Still trying to make sense of the others.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I've been thinking about it... The psalm where is mentioned the beast number (666 or 616 depending the interpretation) is Revelation 13:18 (accordingly to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast) so maybe we can work from here because I'm quite lost right now

Comment: Interesting idea, though in the Christian tradition the "beast" in question is usually not thought of as a devil with horns and tail and so forth, and there are any number of other verses in the bible that talk about the devil or devils.

Comment: I can't help thinking that red + devil just can't possibly be enough to specify a particular year, and that there must be some other information in that picture that we haven't noticed. (Another possibility would be that there's something the others have in common that provides another restriction, but if so I'm not seeing it.)

Comment: The devil's weird smile seems like it might be a hint (and I see some other people have had the same thought) but again I'm not seeing how to get anything useful out of it right now.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan There doesn't seem to be anything else in the picture. A devil(apparently) with a weird smile and huge tail and just a red door...

Comment: @Sid I added some ideas on my answer maybe could be helpful to you.

Comment: I know. Confusing, isn't it? I'd have thought that if there were anything more it would have to be tagged [steganography]. But how do you get an unambiguous date out of a devil and a red door?

Answer (score 15):

Since Door 1 is the only unsolved door, here is my guess:

> The Devil refers to the [Number of the Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast) (usually quoted as 666).

Additionally,

> The [Great Fire of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_London) occurred in the year 1666, which is linked to the red colour due to the fire.

Comment: That is correct! Finally! :) There is one more link - with the devil. :)

Comment: @March Ho, well done!!!

Comment: So 666 indicates the year 1666? OK, then.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I didn't find any good candidates for historically significant events in 666, which is why I decided to try 1666 instead. I was a little skeptical of this answer myself.

Comment: @MarchHo Perhaps it's 1666 instead 666 because you need to "add" the one devil to it's number?

Answer (score 10):

Partial answer:
1st door:

> The 'cat' with the horns and the pointy devil's tail are a clear sign that this might be leading to a very unpleasant place, methinks.

2nd door:

> OK, so the symbol now looks like a snow flake and I think (might be just imagining) the clock change to a notch later. Hmmmmmmm, I'm lost here

3rd door:

> It is a whole number 5776 and refers to "The year of Light" a.k.a. "Beginning of the End of Time". Further on the same: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Lucis the 2016 a.d. actually is anno lucis, or year of light 2016, i.e. the current year!

Comment: 3 more doors to go.

Comment: You are very cold on the second door.

Comment: It is not a star.

Answer (score 10):

Partial Answer

Door nº1 (guesses and why):

> Munich, 1958
>
>  If we take into account that there are 2 clues for each door, in the first one we see that only we have a devil and the door. If so, it can be understood that there's only 1 hint. But if we take Red + Devil we can get to Manchester United. Looking at the history of the club, after playing against the Red Star of Belgrade in 1958 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Manchester_United_F.C._(1945%E2%80%9369) Look for Munich air disaster) happened a tragic air disaster that killed 23 people (most of them players of Manchester United). --> not very related to the date.
>
>
>  Red Devil, Alaska (1921) 
>
>  Dunno if this is just a mere coincidence but if we sum up the number of the beast (666) and the RGB colour for red (255 + 0 + 0) we get 921. Putting a 1 (there's just 1 devil in the image) in front of the 921, we get the foundation date of this poblation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Devil,_Alaska (dunno if correct but looks awesome xDD))
>
>
>  Actually orking on this --> Returning to the idea about the numbe of the beast (666 or 616) we can obtain 2 numbers: 1282 and 1318 (the first one related to the sum of both numbers) and the second related to the psalm where these numbers are mentioned. I dunno how to continue but it's something that I think can be used to follow the thread.

Could be that Door nº2 leads to...

> Napoleonic invasion to Russia

Because:

> The time on the clock is set at 18:12 (I think), and the symbol (asterisk) depicted on the door is related to a snow flake. Napoleon tried to invade Russia during winter and this was one of his biggest mistakes in his military career.

Door nº3:

> @Radoslav Hristov got the solution in this

Door nº4:

> @Gareth MacCaughan got the solution in this

Answer:

> I would take the door that guides to our current year, in fact it is the obvious solution since you want to be in your time!

Comment: You are right for door number 2. Door number 3 was solved by Radoslav and 4 by Gareth.

Comment: Therefore only door nº1 is left?

Comment: Yes. Only door 1 is left.

Comment: Your assumption for door 1 is not correct. It doesn't lead to a specific year.

Comment: The fact that the devil is not painted is relevant?

Comment: Hmm I got two possible numbers for door nº1 but none of them are really a date... Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is my choice(Partial answer) (I know it can be wrong, but I just want to answer)

Door 4

> credits to @GarethMcCaughan : Weeel...I definitely wont go there

Door 3

> credits to @RadoslavHristov : yeah! no one wants to go there

Door 2
As OP commented @Yandrakus is right about 2nd Door :

> 2nd door represents Napoleonic invasion to Russia : so not there

and at last, my original assumpsion

> The devil at Door 1 is smiling, It can be costume party, so lets go through there and enjoy!

Comment: No, it is not a costume party.

Comment: but is the answer right, and reasoning wrong?? or both are wrong

Comment: The answer is incorrect. Think further. :)

Comment: So... 'door one is way to hell', that is why not that one and door three is 5776 i.e (2015-2016), so take that and you will return to present

Answer (score 4):

Door 1

> Old Catholic churches used red doors to remind parishioners of Christ’s blood and that it was a place  free from devil.

Door 2

> Napoleon attacks Russia. (Credit to @Yandrakus)

Door 3

> Refers to the current year(2016)(credit to @RadoslavHristov)

Door 4

> Refers to 1773, the year of the Boston Tea Party (credit to @GarethMccaughan

Hence,

> We should choose Door No.3

Comment: Door 1 is not correct - it doesn't lead to a specific year.

Answer (score 3):

First one:

> Hell. Obviously

Second:

> Purgatory. My understanding is that you suffer and then head to Heaven.

Third:

> This world - it looks like an apartment building door.

Fourth:

> Heaven. from the quote.

So I'd choose

> 4.

Note:

> I am not familiar with Christian theology. Sorry if I mixed things up.

Comment: Nope. Not even close. Note the history tag. The clues are there - two clues for each door.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer but :

> I think you should not take the **orange door** : the inscription is a Bible psalm. ( Psalm 73:17).
>  "Their final destiny" refers to the destiny of the **wicked**, if we read the [entire psalm](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2073). If we open this door, we will be destroyed by God!

Comment: Well, it is indeed a Bible psalm.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

> Door 2 goes to the year 610, the year when Mohammed started preaching.

Comment: This is not the year and it does not take into account the other clue.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've discovered the door 1

> It probably leads to a medieval Church in a medieval time
>  Old catholic churches had a door, called the Devil's door. Which were in first, doors in the North parth of churches, believed to be the Devil's part in the Church, or a not sacred part. After a while it was said that was a door to the Devil leave the Church after a baptism of a child.

Answer (score 3):

## Wrap-up:  The Making Of [Where do all the doors lead to?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41490/where-do-all-the-doors-lead-to)

*This is not a solution to the puzzle, but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been [approved by the community](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

***Caution:** This post may contain spoilers.*

---

#### Inspiration

I wanted to do something related to choosing a door from several differently colored doors for a long time. The idea came from a book - The Neverending Story by Michael Ende.

#### Creative and logistical steps

At the beginning, I considered making clues on the ceiling/floor, but at the end - I discarded them. For the ceiling, I thought of subtly hiding the RGB values (with similar colours - that would be almost undetectable when looked at the picture itself, but with  little corrections would be clearly visible). I also thought of making the doors using the same set of numbers for the RGB values. Even though, at this point I had no clear idea what the doors would hide, I chose a set of colors for the doors, and saved the picture. Then I created the ceiling. Since I had no idea what the puzzle would be like yet, I left the images in a folder and let them rest there for a few days.

I had no idea what would be hiding behind each of the doors. I thought: one of them should be safe, the others should be dangerous. But apart from that - no idea. Once the History challenge started, I already knew - the doors would lead to not-so-pleasant history events and the safe one would lead to the present.

Once I had a clear idea, even though I wanted to use pictures in the beginning, having in mind my poor drawing skills, I started writing it as a story, describing every door and what the character sees. Mid-writing I changed my mind - and decided it would be better if I used visuals. So I tried my best drawing them (although it might not seem like I did from the result). At the end, I put all the necessary clues in the walls/doors so I discarded the idea for the ceiling/floor. I even changed the colors of the doors. Basically, nothing was left from my initial creative process.

At this point I needed 3 events that would be sufficiently different from each other.
First one:

> I first started with fire. Obviously, the door would be red - to symbolise fire. Then I started looking for events related to fire in history - the event needed to famous/big enough. Thus, I searched greatest fires in history. One of the tenth events in a list was the Great Fire of London in 1666 - "666! How well fitting!"
>  So I decided to use this event and draw a devil to symbolize the number and the fire at the same time - after all the devil is strongly connected to hell and hell is fire.

Second one:

> I had an event with fire, so I wanted the opposite - an event with ice. This led to the light blue colour of the door. So I searched for famous winter battles and Napoleon seemed like a good choice. Then I decided to hide the year in a clock. To make it a little more clear the event happened in the winter, I decided to draw a snowflake. However, due to my poor drawing skills, the snowflake was mistaken for a star and that led to totally different assumption from people. Also, it seemed my clock was not correctly drawn and needed a little nudge. So I changed the second image in the process, fixed the clock and replaced the "starflake" with an asterisk - as it looked more like a snowflake.

Third one:

> I had fire, I had snow, so I thought of something orange/autumn related. However, I couldn't find any distinctive events related to autumn. Not that there aren't any famous ones, but 'autumn' is not really your first thought when you think of them. Then I searched for famous events throughout history, hoping one of them would pop out of the screen and hit me on the head. And suddenly, it happened - the Boston Tea Party seemed distinctive enough and orangish enough on top of that. So now I had to figure out ways to hide the year. I searched the year in Google - nothing interesting. Then I separated it into two two-digit numbers and searched again. The first results were a Surah from the Al-Qur'an. Then I thought there should be some psalm in the Bible that would fit. And there was. So I put the psalm above the door - it seemed fitting enough. Then I decided to put a tea leaf on the door and searched for tea leaves images. I found one that was simplistic enough and on a transparent background. I reduced its size and put it on the door.

Fourth one:

> This one was the hardest for me. I didn't want it to be green - as green is usually associated to be "safe". And I didn't want to make it too obvious. I had blue, red and orange, so I went for yellow. The door should lead to the present. But 2016 - regardless of how is given, would be too obvious. So I wanted to use a different calendar. I went for the Hebrew one. Now I had to obfuscate the number somehow, but didn't want to use any of the approaches I have already used. I couldn't think of anything creative enough, so I just split the number into two parts and left them on each side of the door. Then I tried thinking of something that could refer to the "present". I thought of putting a drawing of a gift on the door, but that would have been too obvious. Then I thought of using a kanji - but they were used in a recent puzzle and there ought to be people here who knew them, so it would have been too easy. At the end, I figured out the year should be enough.

#### Resources

For the drawing I used mainly Paint and Gimp2.
For the research - google and what sites it led me to.

#### Takeaway

- Despite the fact that I thought the yellow door was the one with least information, it was solved first.
- Before posting the puzzle, I thought that the red door would be easy to solve, while in fact it took the longest. Perhaps, I should have added some reassuring hints on the image itself.